# ¿Cómo convertir imagen en cadena base 64 C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Tengo este método para convertir una imagen  a una cadena base 64 para luego asignarla desde JQuery a un tag de tipo imagen…pero me di cuenta que solo está codificando el path de la imagen, cuando decodifico me queda algo como esto:

*ClientApp/dist/assets/ProfileImageGirls/Avatar_56106a30-ce82-452e-9bfc-3861a1fc9069.JPG*

¿Como lo puedo resolver?

Metodo:

```
   public string CodeBase64(string path)
        {
            string cadenaBase64 = string.Empty;
            using (Image image = Image.FromFile(path))
            {
                using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
                    byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();
                    cadenaBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                }
            }

            return cadenaBase64;
        }
```

Comment: El código luce bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probé el código que publicaste y funciona.

Por si es de interés, comparto el código que utilizo para convertir cualquier archivo a Base64.

```
public string CodificaBase64(string path)
{
    using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(path))
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        fileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
    }
}
```